# group_by education - rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, activerecord

I am building a prototype of a education application using Rails 3, omniauth and the facebook graph api. So when a User log in to my application he uses his facebook account, I grab all his education history and his friends education_history.

I would like to group every User friends education likes this: 
[image]

I have tried something like this:

```
<ul class="friends-list">
<%= current_user.friends.group_by(&:highschool_name) do |highschool_name| 
 p "<li>#{highschool_name}</li>"
 end
 %>
</ul>
```

And I get a syntax error.

The User tabel look like this:

```
[id, name, image, location, highschool_name, highschool_year, college_name, college_year, graduteschool_name, graduate_year ]
```

And the Friend tabel looks like this:

```
[id, uid, name, image, higschool_name, college_name, graduateschool_name, user_id]
```

How do solve my problem using active record, without loops because their are not effectivity.. right?

Comment: What does the syntax error say?

Comment: @DVG, error says: both block arg and actual block given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `p` or `puts` in ERB files. Think of ERB files as one big string concatenated together. Like `"string 1" + "string 2" + "string 3"`.

That's all ERB does - it just pastes strings together into one big string. You can't call `puts` inside this concatenation operation. So everything in the ERB file needs to be a string. The output from a `puts` call just 'goes up in smoke' since a `puts` call does not return a string, it writes to `stdout` instead.

Next we look at `group_by`: it returns a `Hash`:

```
---------------------------------------------------- Enumerable#group_by
     enum.group_by {| obj | block }  => a_hash
------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Returns a hash, which keys are evaluated result from the block,
     and values are arrays of elements in enum corresponding to the key.

        (1..6).group_by {|i| i%3}   #=> {0=>[3, 6], 1=>[1, 4], 2=>[2, 5]}
```

So putting everything together we could do something like this:

```
<% current_user.friends.group_by(&:highschool_name).each do |hsname, friends| %>
   <% next if hsname.blank? %>
   <li><%= hsname %></li> 
   <% friends.each do |friend| %>
     <%= image_tag(friend.img_url) %> # <- Or wherever you get the img url from 
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks for that awesome explanation, I get this error now: undefined method `highscool_name'

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake - Oops, was a typo in my code. Reload for latest edit.

Comment: alright. It outputs first all of the Users friends and then outputs every highschool_name twice for every user..

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake Casper's code looks correct. Please update your code above to what you're currently using and we can help find your typo

Comment: @Casper, I am sorry mates. I noticed now that the app have double save the friends. You code is right

Comment: @Casper, It still renders first all the users friends, likte this: http://postimage.org/image/tgyl9f27n/

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake - Please post the HTML source of the rendered page. You can upload it to something like pastebin or gist.github.com.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott, do you know why I get all Users friends output first and then the grouping part? Do you have the same output?

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake - The first item on the page is an empty `<li></li>`. It means that user has a bunch of friends that have no `highschool_name`. Something must be wrong in your setup or database. Maybe the user has friends that are not in any school? The code I posted is working exactly as it should..it's just displaying what your DB contains.

Comment: @Casper, yes there is some users that have no highschool_name, but it doesent make sens why the code have to output all the users friends first and then outputs the grouping part. Do you have any suggest of how I can fix this?

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake - You need to brush up on your Ruby skills. You can't continue to program Rails without knowing how Ruby works. You will never get anywhere like that. All your questions that you post are basic Ruby questions, which show you have problems with the language. Get a book on just Ruby and learn the language before you try and work with Rails. **MINIMUM** go through all lessons of http://rubykoans.com/ . In the meantime see my edit. I added a condition which skips all users that have no highschool.

Comment: @Casper, Right now I have one Ruby book and the RubyOnRails tut book. I love the language and I am trying to brush my skills as much as I can. Thanks for the link, I will go through the lessons.